# Python request throwing error IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Writing path is :

> write_path = 'C:\Users\hgdht\Desktop\Downloader_Automation'

i get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'ciarb_annual_review_2011_c
.pdf?sfvrsn=2'
```

Here is the code:

```
import os
import csv
import requests

write_path = r'C:\Users\hgdht\Desktop\Downloader_Automation'  # ASSUMING THAT FOLDER EXISTS!

with open('final.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for link in spamreader:
        print('-'*72)
        print(link)
        pdf_file = link[0].split('/')[-1]
        with open(os.path.join(write_path, pdf_file), 'wb') as pdf:
            try:
                # Try to request PDF from URL
                print('TRYING {}...'.format(link[0]))
                a = requests.get(link[0], stream=True)
                for block in a.iter_content(512):
                    if not block:
                        break

                    pdf.write(block)
                print('OK.')
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This will catch ONLY Requests exceptions
                print('REQUESTS ERROR:')
                print(e)  # This should tell you more details about the error
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: did you try this `write_path = 'C:\\Users\\hgdht\\Desktop\\Downloader_Automation'` ? do you have `ciarb_annual_review_2011_c.pdf?sfvrsn=2'` file in your machine ? If yes, which location?

Comment: `?` is an invalid character in a filename on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Because you have Have some some special characters in your saving name. try to clean them and remove spaces or any other character with `_`. May be this will help you.